# How do I seperate computing and network I/O for each record in a hadoopRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running a spark grep application on my 1 node spark cluster. (Itself is the master and slave). I have a text file of 913MB on a remote source on hdfs server. Text file is divided into chunks of 128MB with replication set to none. My spark application reads the text file and applies a filter transformation, to search for a keyword and then in the output to hdfs, only outputs lines with that keyword. To get insights of working of spark, I logged more details in the spark source code and build it to run the modified version. I logged bytes read information using reader.getpos() in getNext(K,V) in hadoopRDD.scala upto 10 records. I also log some message in the filter operation to get when the computing actually starts. As spark uses lazy loading the log in filter shows before any bytes of data have been read. So I tried reading the complete iterator before a filter operation using:

```
while(iter.hasNext){
  logInfo(s"value of the iterator: ${iter.next}")
}
```

The above code logs the next line in the text file, every time a record has been read (record here would be a line in text file as a default hadoop read recorder operation). But does not perform any filtering after that and I get an empty output. If I just print a log after a filtering operation, with the result, it only shows up after all the records have been read and hadoop reader is closed.

**I am trying to separate computing and Network I/O at least for the first set of bytes to show a performance bottleneck, but I am not sure if spark is actually performing computation on each record or once all the records are read for a task? and how do I compute it separately?**